# Working with openlayers and typescript classes

Tags: class, typescript, openlayers

```
/// <reference path="openlayers.d.ts" />

class MapComponent {
    element: HTMLElement;
    map: OpenLayers.Map;

    constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
        // Setup our map object
        this.element = element;
        this.map = new OpenLayers.Map(this.element);
    }

    init() {
        // Setup our two layer objects
        var osm_layer_map = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OSM");

        // Add layers to the map
        this.map.addLayers([osm_layer_map]);

        // Add a layer switcher control
        this.map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({}));

        // Zoom the map to the max extent
        if (!this.map.getCenter()) {
            this.map.zoomToMaxExtent();
        }
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    var el = document.getElementById('map');
    var mc = new MapComponent(el);
    mc.init();
}
```

I have the above piece of code to work with a simple HTML file with only 1  of ID, 'map' with style: height and width @ 500px.

I have tried several other ways to get the map to display but so far all i got was a white page (blank).

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Solutions tried so far:

- using jquery with ready function
- replace `window.onload` with a call direct from the html, `<script><script/>`
- place `document.getElementById()` in the new `OpenLayers.Map(here);` when first creating `this.map`
- placing the `window.onload` call above and below (currently)
- using export class or public `init()` or both

As of now, I just want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that creating the map with the element provided and later defining the options doesn't work.

Instead either initialize the map with options

```
    var options = {
        projection: "EPSG:3857",
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-200000, -200000, 200000, 200000),
        center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(-12356463.476333, 5621521.4854095)
    };

    this.map = new OpenLayers.Map(this.element, options);
```

Or call `this.map.render(this.element)` at the end of your init method.

Also make sure your div is actually visible and has some size specified, otherwise it might be not visible...